# Help to make appendix look decent

Tags: graphics, header-footer, appendix, scalebox, wide-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK4b2.png)[image]

Hope someone can help me make these appensix´s look just a little bit better or has some tricks to make the image appear bigger :)

Comment: You have a lot of wasted space in one of the columns, and still some space left to the right.  Is there some reason you lined up the columns in the separate block?  I would be more specific except the images are illegible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post code, not pictures.  Don't ignore errors.  Don't use scalebox on a table.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have such a wide fifth column? It adds nothing to the reader's comprehension but, as you found, messes up the appearance of your table. Reduce the space you allocate for that portion of your table. You obviously know how the set the column widths so I leave it to you to apply the LaTeX skills that you have demonstrated for other columns. --- GOM

Comment: I don't think OP knows how to set column widths.  It looks like the fifth column is wide because of the other table.  But without a bit more effort on their part, I'm not all that inclined to spend time deciphering that image.